# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}\mathbb{E}\big((|X_n|\mathbb{1}_{|X_n|\leq n})^{1+\epsilon}\big)}<\infty,~~\forall\epsilon>0 $

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of random variable, such that:

$$
(1)~.~~~\sup_n\mathbb E  (|X_n|)<\infty\Rightarrow
$$
$$
(2)~.~~~\dfrac{M_j}{2}<\int_{j-1<|X_n|\leq j}{|X_{n}(t)|d\mathbb{P}(t)}\leq M_j+\dfrac{1}{j^2} \qquad\forall n\geq 1 \text{ et }1\leq j\leq n^2
$$
with $M_j>0$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{M_j}<\infty$,and
$$
(3)~.~~~\{|X_n|\mathbb{1}_{|X_n|\leq n}\} \text{ is uniformly integrable},
$$
furthermore 
$$ 
(4)~.~~~\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\mathbb{P}(\{|X_n|>n\})}<\infty.
$$

Show that :
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}\mathbb{E}\big((|X_n|\mathbb{1}_{|X_n|\leq n})^{1+\epsilon}\big)}<\infty,~~\forall\epsilon>0
$$
An idea please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $N_j:=M_j+1/j^2$, so that 
$$\sum_1^\infty N_j<\infty,$$
and for $j\le n$
$$E|X_n|1_{j-1<|X_n|\le j}\le N_j$$
and hence 
$$(j-1)P(j-1<|X_n|\le j)\le E|X_n|1_{j-1<|X_n|\le j}\le N_j,$$
so that for $j=2,\dots,n$
$$P(j-1<|X_n|\le j)\le \frac{N_j}{j-1}\ll\frac{N_j}j,$$
where $a\ll b$ means $a=O(b)$. Since $N_1\ge1$, we have 
$$P(j-1<|X_n|\le j)\ll\frac{N_j}j$$
for all natural $j\le n$. 
So, for $p:=1+\epsilon>1$, 
$$E|X_n|^p 1_{|X_n|\le n}\le\sum_{j=1}^n j^p P(j-1<|X_n|\le j)
\ll\sum_{j=1}^n j^{p-1}N_j$$
and hence 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^p}\,E|X_n|^p 1_{|X_n|\le n}
\ll\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^p}\,\sum_{j=1}^n j^{p-1}N_j
=\sum_{j=1}^\infty j^{p-1}N_j\sum_{n=j}^\infty\frac1{n^p}
\ll\sum_{j=1}^\infty N_j<\infty.$$
Thus,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^p}\,E|X_n|^p 1_{|X_n|\le n}<\infty,$$
as desired.

Comment: why do we have : $\frac{N_j}{j-1}<<\frac{N_j}{j}$ ?

Comment: What is the notion de $O$?

Comment: @AbdessamadEl : $a=O(b)$ means $|a|\le Cb$ for some positive real constant $C$; cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation. In particular, for $j\ge2$ we have $\frac{N_j}{j-1}\ll\frac{N_j}j$, because then $\frac{N_j}{j-1}\le2\frac{N_j}j$.

Comment: @Made : Are you satisfied with this answer?